# Как подключить к макбуку аир 2019 два внешних монитора?

Tags: mac, монитор

меня есть макбук аир 2019 года на i5, докупил я адаптер от Baseus(фото ниже), в нём получается: 1 hdmi, разъём для зарядки и 2 юсбшни. По hdmi подключил один из мониторов, есть ли какой-то способ подключить второй монитор(DisplayLink может быть??)?
Возможно ли это вообще?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решение: просто докупите кабель type-c hdmi и будет вам счастье)

Comment: А куда его воткнуть если оба доступных порта заняты адаптером?

Comment: я в итоге купил другой адаптер, который вставляется в один порт по проводу и второй у меня освободился)